# .Net can't find a Method - Only if native debugging is enabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Two colleagues have issues debugging our program, and we are at our wits end.
I don't expect you to exactly solve our problem, but I would love some pointers or ideas where we could continue to look.

We have a Solution with about 50 C# projects, a few C++ projects and a few c++/cli projects.
We target .net 4.5.2.
They use Visual Studio 2013, I use VS2015 and can't reproduce it.

When trying to debug our program, they get a MissingMethodException - But only if native debugging is enabled! If they start the program directly OR disable native debugging, it runs correctly.
[image]

It claims to be unable to find **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.get_Item(System.String)**, but when we opened the Dll in ILSpy, I can see that Method.

[image]

Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" option.

Comment: Thank you. Enabling Managed Compatibility Mode unfortunately did not have any effect.

Comment: I had the same issue in vs2017, ticking "Use Manage Compatibility Mode" worked for me but I had to clean and recompile my project.